# sed -i is not working on solaris system while removing 1st line from file

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I am trying to remove first line from file where i don't want to create any extra file, i just want to modify current file .Tried following command on solaris machine but following error(sed: illegal option -- i) is coming, can someone suggest replacement for it for solaris.

```
sed -i 1d currentFileName
```

Comment: `sed -e 1d currentFileName > tmp && cat tmp > currentFileName && rm tmp`

Comment: but here tmp will get created which i dont want.

Comment: Try : `sed -i'' -e '1d' filename`

Comment: it is giving error (sed: illegal option -- i) as i mentioned above

Comment: Seems to be your `sed` don't have `-i` option. Use `sed --help` check whether `-i` option is available or not.

Comment: @b22 `sed -i` is just an automatic way of creating a temp file and deleting it afterwards. If you don't want a temp file at all, you can't use `sed -i`.

Comment: (Or)  `sed -e '1d' file > tmp && mv -f tmp file`

Comment: `-i` is a non-standard GNU extension to the `sed` utility.  The standard is here: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: @that other guy : sed -i works on linux machine , there we do not to create any extra file.

Comment: @b22 *sed -i works on linux machine , there we do not to create any extra file*  Actually, you *do* create an "extra" temp file.  You just don't see it, as `sed` creates the temp file internally.  From the [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt):  *-i ... This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
     `sed` does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
     this file rather than to the standard output.* Again, this is a **non-standard GNU extension** to the standard `sed` utility.

Comment: @Andrew Henle : thanks for explaining in detail, i think there is no solution for this on solaris to modify files the way i want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ed` or `vi` :

```
ed -s currentFileName << EOF
1d
w
q
EOF
```